# Text not showing over video loop

Tags: html, css, html5-video

What am I doing wrong with the following example? I'm attempting to create a video loop within a div and have text appear on top of it. Any help is appreciated.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEJPRO

HTML:

```
<div class="clouds">
<video width="600" height="200" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload>
<source src="http://www.eclarify.com/videos/background.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
<source src="http://www.eclarify.com/videos/background.ogg" type="http://leongaban.com/video/ogg" >
<source src="http://www.eclarify.com/videos/background.webm" type="video/webm" >
<object data="http://www.eclarify.com/videos/background.mp4" width="1920" height="1080">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<param name="autoplay" value="true" >
<param name="loop" value="true" >
<embed src="http://www.eclarify.com/videos/background.swf" width="1920" height="1080" wmode="transparent" >
</object>
</video> 

<div class="content">
   <h1>Hello There</h1>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;

}

div.clouds {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

div.content h1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 600px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index:100;
}


div.clouds video, div.clouds object, div.clouds embed {
    /*width: 100%;*/
    width: 2000px;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 720px;
    margin: 0 auto;  
    z-index:-1500;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go buddy

https://codepen.io/facetimechat/pen/ZYJPjM

When you need to overlay one element over another. You usually have to have the second element in absolute position, and position it accordingly to where you want. So in this case

```
div.content h1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 600px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index:100;
  
  /* this will bring your content up */
  position:absolute;
  top:0;

}
```